# GTM - Custom JS - Returning value of a variable unless its empty

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Why this code does not work?

What I want to do is:

Always return a value from variable myid unless its empty/undefined/null - then return googleid

```js
function() {
  var myid = {{myid}};
  var googleid = {{googleid}};
if (myid === '' || myid === undefined || myid === null){
return googleid 
}
else {
return
myid
}
}
```

Both variables separately return values, but this custom JS does not seem to work

Comment: the syntax u have for declaring those two vars, myid and google id, looks wrong, you cant have a nested object without a prop, and your var names will clash with the prop of the deepest object

Comment: modified the code but still does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
if (myid === 'undefined') {
```

in this:

```
if (!myid) {
```

Comment: modified the code but still does not seem to work

Comment: I modified my answer, try the new solution